# Add element to scala ListBuffer in java

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop, listbuffer

If it is possible what would be the easiest way of adding an element to a scala ListBuffer from within java.

this is the scala ListBuffer (in scala)

```
var newModVersion: ListBuffer[NewModVersionEntry] = new ListBuffer[NewModVersionEntry]()
```

and this is what I want to add (in java)

```
XplosionCoreBL.newModVersion().add(new NewModVersionEntry(name, latestVersion, latestMCVersion, isCritical, description));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XplosionCoreBL.newModVersion().$plus$eq(new NewModVersionEntry(name, latestVersion, latestMCVersion, isCritical, description));
```

**In Java, `$plus$eq` corresponds to the [`+=` (append single element) method of `ListBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer).**

Answer (score 0):

```
List<NewModVersionEntry> asJavaList = scala.collection.JavaConversions.bufferAsJavaList(XplosionCoreBL.newModVersion());
asJavaList.add(new NewModVersionEntry(name, latestVersion, latestMCVersion, isCritical, description));
```